# Make react redraw all component, or part of it

Tags: reactjs, render

I have this line of code

```
render() {
    return <img class="animated bounceIn" src={this.state.img_source}></img>
}
```

Animation is played. When I change img_source by setState(), react detects changes only at source of the image, and changes the picture. So animation is not played again.
How can I make animation played again?

Comment: Are the img sources gifs?

Comment: no, just pictures

Comment: If you're using react then class attribute is wrong, you must use className instead

Comment: it would be probably enough to change `key` of the `img` element to trigger a remount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to use "className", not "class" in react JSX. Next, be pragmatic: animation is probably triggered by css and render is redrawn every time you change the state.

```js
export class MyComponent extends React.Component { 
  //... code
  render() {
    return (
      <img 
        className={this.state.className} 
        src={this.state.img_source}
      ></img>)
}
```

It's enough to manage class names in state and them will be applied to your render automagically with the same effects that you would get with other well known libraries as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the React component lifecycle methods.

`componentDidUpdate` will serve the purpose.

```
   componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.img_source !== this.state.img_source) {
            // Redo the animation
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can remove class and then add it again with setTimeout, but I think this is not best soultion

Comment: Make use of componentDidUpdate for applying changes to a class string add useless complexity to a code that is achievable simply with a setState()

Answer (score 0):

Since the animation is triggered by css, then you must remove and add the classes when updating the state of the img src:

```
render() {
    return <img ref={i => {this.img = i}} className={"animated bounceIn"} src={this.state.img_source}></img>
}

componentDidUpdate (pps, pst) {
    if (prevState.img_source !== this.state.img_source) {
        this.img.classList.remove("animated");
        this.img.classList.remove("bounceIn");
        this.img.classList.add("animated");
        this.img.classList.add("bounceIn");
    }
}
```

Using ref you can reference the Dom element and add / remove de classes manually. It's not elegant but it works

Comment: This way to work with componentDidUpdate make the state of the application less predictable, I would not recommend it for simple task as changing a class name, and if I would do through this method, I would still reflect the change in the application state.

Comment: I agree, but toggling the className (with setState) on the img when updating the img source would mean calling setState from componentDidUpdate wich is discouraged

Comment: no need for componentDidUpdate, atomically you have to change class AND image src in setState({ className: 'bounceIn', imgSrc: 'http://xxxx.xxx.jpg'}). Consistent and predictable state is the foundation of  a maintainable React app.

Comment: But in order to replay the animation you must remove the bounceIn class and add it again (according to css-tricks) , unless calling setState with the same className value would trigger the animation

Comment: the code is insufficient to elaborate a complete pattern but, in the way I use transitions, bounceIn would be removed in a setState and another setState will be called in the first setState callback. The point is trying to keep state consistent and predictable and this requirement has higher priority.